# `gas` vs. `gasLimit` fields

Tags: transactions, gas, evm, gas-limit, out-of-gas

I am trying to submit a transaction with a gas limit set. In the [documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/), I find a field referred to as `gasLimit` with the following description

```
gasLimit – the maximum amount of gas units that can be consumed by the transaction. The EVM specifies the units of gas required by each computational step
```

and example

```
{
  from: "0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8",
  to: "0xac03bb73b6a9e108530aff4df5077c2b3d481e5a",
  gasLimit: "21000",
  maxFeePerGas: "300",
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: "10",
  nonce: "0",
  value: "10000000000"
}
```

However, when I try to set `gasLimit` using `web3.py` I get an error stating the field is not recognized. Instead it seems `gas` is the field to set the limit with. This is also shown on the same documentation site in a field below

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "account_signTransaction",
  "params": [
    {
      "from": "0x1923f626bb8dc025849e00f99c25fe2b2f7fb0db",
      "gas": "0x55555",
      "maxFeePerGas": "0x1234",
      "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0x1234",
      "input": "0xabcd",
      "nonce": "0x0",
      "to": "0x07a565b7ed7d7a678680a4c162885bedbb695fe0",
      "value": "0x1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I safely assume that setting the `gas` field limits the gas consumption of the transaction to be below the amount I set? Does it do the same that I would assume `gasLimit` to do? Why does the term `gasLimit` appear then explicitly as a transaction field in the documentation?

NOTE: I tried manually on Goerli and it does seem to be the case that `gas` can be used to set the limit. However, I am confused by the usage of both terms and would appreciate a confirmation.